# What defines a transportation-related medical expense to be "primarily for, and essential to, medical care"?

Tags: united-states, hsa, travel, eligible-expenses

I'm trying to understand which transportation-related medical expenses are IRS-Qualified Medical Expenses for  health savings accounts (HSA).

I understand that [Publication 969](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p969.pdf) defines what HSAs are, including what counts as qualified medical expenses for HSAs:

> Qualified medical expenses are those expenses that generally would qualify for
>   the medical and dental expenses deduction. These are
>   explained in Pub. 502, Medical and Dental Expenses. [+ adding some exceptions to it specific to HSA].

[Publication 502](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p502.pdf) indicates:

> You can include in medical expenses amounts paid for
>   transportation primarily for, and essential to, medical care.

Does the IRS gives any guidance regarding what defines a transportation-related medical expense to be *primarily* for, and *essential* to, medical care?

For example, does the *primarily* mean I should stay more than X% of the time in a medical facility?  Does the *essential* mean I couldn't find a similar treatment closer to my place? etc.